# Include php file that includes another php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, global-variables

My PhP files contain some long string constants and I'm trying to factor them out. So I created "my_string_constants.php" and used `include` in `header.php`. So far that works fine.

Now another file, `page.php` also requires the string constants *and* `header.php`. The scheme below tries to clarify these dependendies.

[image]

The string constants now seem available in my header only, not the rest of my page. I tried to resolve this by adding `global ...` to each string constant in `string_constants.php`. This resolved the error of "Unknown variable" but my string constants still seem unavailable to most of the page content.

What's the right way to get this working?

**UPDATE**

The **issue's been solved**. I should have used `define(myString` instead of `$myString = ...`. By doing so, I need just one `include` in `header.php` and the constants will be available to `page.php` as well.

Thanks a million, you guys are great.

Comment: Your setup is unclear. You include or require file once in the top most file if you have to do it in an explicit manner. `page.php` and `header.php` cannot _both_ be the top most file called in a request. If you really have to include a file in both, then use `ìnclude_once()` or `require_once()`.

Comment: if `page.php` needs `header` and `constants`, but `header` already has `constants`... then `page.php` only needs `header`

Comment: @mistermartin I tried that but it's triggering an error: `Notice: Undefined variable: re_afornone_ov in C:\xampp\htdocs\t\wp-content\themes\c\home_page.php ` The string constants are available to `header.php` but not `homepage.php` but they both need them.

Comment: So they are string variables, not string constants.  Constants can't be changed and don't need to be declared global.

Comment: Can you add the code on how you included the file? DIR hierarchy may be an issue to your problem.

Comment: @MandeKira: all .php files involved are in a single folder.

Comment: @RubenGeert when you say "string constants" we assume you're referring to [constants](http://php.net/constants). As Devon mentioned, an "undefined variable" notice will not be triggered if you're actually using constants.

Comment: @Devon they don't need to be changed. They're basically just sentences like "bananas are green" but much longer. I could copy-paste them into my main template files but this kinda clutters up the code and causes redundancy because several different files need the exact same string constants.

Comment: @mistermartin ah, my bad I think. They're declared like `$someString = 'blah...';` That's -technically- not a true constant in Php?

Comment: @RubenGeert correct, that is not a true constant. Using true constants should resolve the issue.

Comment: Those variables should be available across files.  Changing to a constant doesn't resolve cross-file availability, it resolves scope issues such as accessing the value within a function, for example.

Comment: @RubenGeert, if you can do `$someString = 'blah...'; $someString = 'something else';` then it isn't a constant in any language.

Comment: **You are doing this the wrong way** if this is WordPress.  Is `page.php` part of your theme? If so, define your constants in your theme's `functions.php` file, and you are DONE.  You do not have to include header, bootstrap, etc - that's all handled automatically by WordPress (I've added the WP tag to your question, as that's a VERY important detail).

Comment: @cale_b thanks for the advice! I'll do just that!

Comment: I'd recommend DELETING this question.  It's misleading, as are the answers, as the fact that it's WordPress changes everything, and the answers aren't pertinent to WordPress.

Comment: @cale_b I'm not sure: the answers are getting the job done *in Wordpress* as we speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you would want to do is distinguish a constant from a variable.  Especially if other developers end up working on this, they will be confused by your terminology.

For constants, you do not need to declare them as global and they are defined like so:

```
define('MY_CONSTANT', 'Value');
```

It seems to me that the constants file is acting as your site wide configuration file, so to me, it makes sense to have that on every page, regardless of whether header is used or not.  I would normally create a bootstrap file for this purpose.

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/constants.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/database.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/session.php');
```

You get the point, then every accessible page needs to include this bootstrap file and then possibly the header.

page.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/header.php');
?>
<h1>Page Title</h1>
```

In header.php, since it requires these constants, you can handle this in two ways, either check that the constants are defined (meaning, bootstrap was included first) or just use another require_once to make sure that file was loaded.

```
if (!defined('MY_CONSTANT')) exit('Bootstrap failure');
```

or

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap/constants.php');
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to consult the manual on this for a couple of minutes.

Comment: it appears from a comment that he's also using wordpress... if that makes any difference to how things are *already* organized.

Comment: @mister martin: Yes, it's Wordpress indeed.

Comment: IF this in fact a WordPress question, then all of this is irrelevant.  OP needs to define his constants in his theme's `functions.php` file, and does NOT need to do the include(s), etc per this (and other) answers.

Answer (score 1):

Going to many directories or "files" deep regarding includes can really cause issues later when you are trying to debug.  As a rule I try to only go one level deep in regards to including files.  I.e.  Create a folder called includes and place everything in there.  If there is a file that needs multiple variables, functions etc, then include them in the needed pages at that point doing several includes like so:

```
<?php 
include("includes/header.php"); 
includes("includes/functions.php");
?>
```

There are also other issues in regards to having multiple includes, like if you have sessions or cookies some LAMP stacks will require you to declare

```
session_start();
```

at the top of every page including all included php files that may need access to that session or cookie.

So to answer your question I believe the simplest solution would be to re-organize your site or script.

Answer (score 0):

in the header page ontop u write
include 'header.php';

and in header.php you write
include 'my_string_constants.php';

so in this case the page.php calls the header and in the header the my_string_constants is being called...is this what you mean?

Comment: Is this an answer? It doesn't feel like one, it feels like a comment....